# can Jquery val() use HTML Value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my code

```
 $("#bt3").click(function() {
     $(function() {
             $("#response").val("<span class='red'>Hello> <b>Again</b></span>"));
     });
 });
```

and this script use by this code line :

```
<textarea name="response" id="response" cols="85" rows="9"></textarea>
```

but i want output in textrea

> hello again

not,

```
<span class='red'>Hello> <b>Again</b></span>
```

---

I also got advice to use jquery text editor , can give the best advice for a plugin that can be used ?

Comment: Your second question is separate, but unfortunately SO does not manage recommendation questions well. Instead, ask a new question and describe what you need to use the editor for.

Comment: what you are looking for is a WYSIWYG editor, like CKEditor, TinyMCE, or Kendo's Editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three options available for you:

1. Use an WYSIWYG editor like [THIS](http://jqueryte.com/demos) one.
2. Use an `contentEditable` div which will serve your purpose.
3. Use a `regex` to strip `html` tags from textarea's value like:

   `var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");`

I'll suggest you to think about first two.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strip the html tags and get the plain text you can replace

```
$("#response").val("<span class='red'>Hello> <b>Again</b></span>"));
```

with

```
$("#response").val($("<span class='red'>Hello <b>Again</b></span>").text());
```

FYI: HTML formatting cannot be applied within `textarea`. You will need a WYSIWYG editor for this.